# How to write in a text box python or html

Tags: python, html, web, passwords

So, I wanted to make something to automatically sign me into my twitter account. How would I use python, or HTML, to go to twitter.com/login and automatically put in my username and password, and then submits it?

Comment: Use a password manager for your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called Web automation. In Python, I recommend [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org). It's pretty much all you need. The documentation is quite good and you can find examples online.

Note: use passwd for your password! Keep it safe

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to go through browser automation to access data in twitter. What you really need is a [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation). There are [multiple Python clients](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries#python), like [`tweepy`](http://www.tweepy.org/) or [`python-twitter`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter/).

Comment: That is a better way to go at it 